# Empty object on Client side. How to correctly pass promises values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, client-server

I've got problem with object which contains promises values and with accessing them on the Cilent side. I want to have access to the values but all I've received was empty object.

Here is the code on server-side:

```
router.get('/toExcess', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.query);  
  const response = logic.adder(req.query.a, req.query.b);
  const convertToModular = logic.modularRecordExcess(response);
  const convertToOpposite = logic.oppositeRecordExcess(response);
  const convertToObjective = logic.objectiveRecordExcess(response);
  convertToObjective.then(function (response) {
   var add = {
   modular: convertToModular,
   opposite: convertToOpposite,
   objective: convertToObjective,
 }
 console.log(add);
 res.send(add);
}).catch(function(err){

});
});
```

and it's console log on server-side:

```
 { modular: Promise { [ '1.', '0111', '.', '1001', '0011' ] },
  opposite: Promise { [ '1.', '1000', '.', '0110', '1100' ] },
  objective: Promise { [ '1.', '1000', '.', '0110', '1101' ] } }
```

and here is react function:

```
showExcess(){
  document.querySelector('.input-wrapper').style.display = 'inline';
  RestClient.getExcess(this.state.augend, this.state.addend).then((response) 
  => {    
this.setState({
      isReady: true
  });
      console.log(response);
  });
}
```

and the consol.log result in browser:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbCPk.jpg)

the object is empty.
Any suggestions? I need to have access to values from modular, objective and opposite.

Comment: Resolve your promises first. Resolve.all([convertToModular, opposite, objective]).then(res.json);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
router.get('/toExcess', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.query);  
  const response = logic.adder(req.query.a, req.query.b);
  const convertToModular = logic.modularRecordExcess(response);
  const convertToOpposite = logic.oppositeRecordExcess(response);
  const convertToObjective = logic.objectiveRecordExcess(response);
  Promise.all([convertToModular, convertToOpposite, convertToObjective])
  .then(function (response) {
   var add = {
      modular: response[0],
      opposite: response[1],
      objective: response[2],
   }
  console.log(add);
  res.send(add);
  //or you can pass res.json(response);
  })
 .catch(function(err){

 });
});
```